# Как открыть ссылку в новой вкладке?

Tags: gwt, java

Пытаюсь заставить приложение открывать ссылку в новой вкладке, но ничего не получается. Согласно документации есть 4 спец. значения для открытия ссылки:

> **_blank** - Обозначенный ссылкой документ всегда загружается во вновь открытое
> окно
>
> **_self** - Документ загружается в этот же кадр или окно как исходный
>
> **_parent** - Загрузка документа в родительское окно или набор кадров,
> содержащий кадр с гипертекстовой
> ссылкой. Если ссылка находится в окне
> или кадре верхнего уровня, это
> эквивалентно значению _self
>
> **_top** - Загрузка документа в окно, содержащее гипертекстовую ссылку, с
> заменой всех кадров, отображенных в
> окне в данный момент

Пользуюсь методом класса [Window](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html):

```
Window.open(link, "_blank", "");
```

Но ссылка открывается только во всплывающем окне (всплывающие окна у многих юзеров вообще заблокированы). Как открыть эту ссылку в новом окне/вкладке, а не во всплывающем?

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, поведение при открытии ссылки с target="_blank" (или через window.open()) специфично для каждого браузера. Например, в Firefox есть галочка в настройках "Open new windows in new tabs instead", что подразумеват, что по умолчанию он открывает их в новых окнах. А вот Chrome сразу открывает их в новых вкладках.

Comment: Дело в том, что здесь проблема не в браузерах, а в GWT. Потому что во всех браузерах поведение одинаковое - открывается ВСПЛЫВАЮЩЕЕ окно. Чтобы открывалось либо новое окно, либо новая вкладка (в зависимости от браузера) - это как раз то, что хотелось бы видеть и как оно и должно работать, согласно документации.

Comment: А каким образом вы вызываете Window.open? Честно говоря, с gwt не знаком, только что поставил, скомпилировал тестовый пример (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/gettingstarted.html) и добавил в обработчик нажатия кнопки вызов 
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open("http://ya.ru", "_blank", "");
 - открылась новая вкладка, фаер не заблокировал.

Заметил также, что один и тот же вызов на чистом js window.open() дает разные результаты в зависимости от того, выполняется этот код при загрузке страницы или в обработчике, например, onclick ссылки. Может, у вас такая же ситуация?

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что метод `Window.open`, как ни странно, действительно, должен открывать новое окно, а не вкладку. По крайней мере, это видно из его названия ;).

Ни стандарты html, ни javascript — никто ничего не знает про вкладки, поскольку это искусственное добавление со стороны браузеров. Так что всё зависит от браузера. Мне логичным видится следующее (как я понимаю, так и сделано в том же Хроме или Огнелисе): щелчок по обычному `<a href=… target="_blank" … >` откроет новую вкладку, а js `Window.open` откроет новое окно. Плюс в некоторых браузерах (в FF и в IE, насчёт остальных не знаю) есть настройка «никогда не открывать окна, всегда открывать вкладки».

Короче, мораль: этот процесс Вы контролировать никак не можете.

---

Вы, наверняка, удивитесь, но лучший выход из ситуации — вообще не заниматься этим бредом. Почитайте, например, [$43 Ководства](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/43/).

Comment: Вкладка или окно - разницы не имеет. Речь идет о всплывающих окнах (см. коммент для yozh). По поводу ссылки - это применимо к веб-сайтам, но далеко не всегда применимо к веб-приложениям. Открытие в новых вкладках в веб-приложениях встречается очень часто. Например, открыв главную страницу docs.google.com вы получаете список документов и при клике на один из них документ откроется именно в новой вкладке/окне. Потому что иначе, если открывать все документики в одной странице, допустим, в TabbedPane, тупо не хватит памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Всё правильно. Есть такая проблема в JavaScript безотносительно Gwt. Если использовать window.open (с параметром blank), то результат может быть разный. Если по стеку вызовов определяется, что в window.open мы пришли из обработки события (например, onclick), то во всех браузерах будет открываться новое окно/вкладка. А если у нас window.open вызывается из другого места, например, мы отправили серверу запрос и при получении ответа от сервера попытаемся открыть какой-то url, то во всех браузерах это также откроет новое окно/вкладку... кроме Хрома. В хроме откроется всплывающее окно!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://XXXXXXXXX" target="_blank" onclick="popupWin = window.open(this.href, 'contacts', 'location,width=390,height=218,left=170,top=120'); popupWin.focus(); return false;">
    <IMG SRC="http://адрес кнопки/inbookmark_2.gif" BORDER="10" WIDTH="136" HEIGHT="16">
</a>
```

Или так

```
<a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" title="Подписаться на RSS" target="_blank" OnClick="javascript:mywin = window.open('http://skr-silniy.org/?feed=rss2', 'mywin', '); mywin.moveTo(0,0);return false;">
    <IMG SRC="http://адрес кнопки/feed.gif" width=16 height=16 border=0>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь точно будет как](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=29&id=342)